# Remove TAX amount text on cart and checkout Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to dispay total cart price without break down the amount of taxes separately. 
I have made a simulation image with chrome debug , how it should be.

This is how it should display:  **9,72 € (Iva incluido)**

After try several codes, I can't find the solution. It seem to do nothing when I introduce them in the functions.php, maybe they go in another template?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use CSS here

Comment: Hi, That element has the class " woocommerce-Price-amount amount " If i hide that class, a lot of prices on the page disappear. How can i solve that?

I only want to hide the tax amount number, not all the line.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific question, hiding the amount with css would be:

```
.woocommerce .includes_tax .amount {
    display: none;
}
```